# Spring MVC - Setting dispatcher url pattern to "/" causes controllers not to work and 404 errors

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

WEB XML:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

redirect.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% response.sendRedirect("index.htm"); %>
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class RedirectController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.htm")
    public ModelAndView goHome() {
        ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("index");
        return modelView;
    }
```

With this configuration, my project runs properly and my index.jsp page will load properly on the URL: http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/index.htm, but I need my project to take more than just .htm requests. I change the servlet mapping in the web.xml to :

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

which I read should be able to handle all URL requests. When I build and run my project, I get a glassfish 404 error at the URL: http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/. From what I know, if '/' handle all requests, then redirect.jsp's redirect to index.htm should still invoke my controller and forward the page to index.jsp. Any help is appreciated

I have tried '/*' as well and it does not help

Dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.controller"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />

    <bean id="RedirectController" class="controller.RedirectController"/>
```

Comment: `*.htm` is a kind of resource,you need avoid to use them a request,and you need to show your spring configuration,is all your jsp in the `WEB-INF` folder?

Comment: Yes all my jsps are in there., which files would you like to see? the dispatcher?

Comment: I have set redirect.jsp to redirect to "/index" and set the controller mapping also to "/index", it still results in 404 at  http://localhost:8080/ProjectName. I think for some reason the welcome file is not working

Comment: the `viewResolver`,due to your modeview is set to index,and you need to tell it,if it is a jsp file or a html file

Comment: hi, I have made an edit including the dispatcher

Comment: is your index.jsp in the `web-inf/jsp` folder?

Comment: Yes it is in there, but I do not that is the problem, since the controller is not even invoked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168155/discussion-between-lucumt-and-billy-kong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your controller code,you have import the wrong `ModelAndView`
you need to import it from

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
```

instead of import from

```
org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView
```

Answer (score 0):

you can map many urls to one method

so it should work if you add a second mapping to your goHome Method

```
@RequestMapping({"/", "/index.htm"})
public ModelAndView goHome() {
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("index");
    return modelView;
}
```

Comment: if you add the `"/"`-mapping to your goHome-Method, the `<welcome-file-list>`-Tag in web.xml and `redirect.jsp` are no longer needed